# Mongodb: Is it possible to create ISODate field in Aggregation Pipeline from an existing string field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to limit a result set on a collection which has a "date_modified" field unfortunately set as a string. I'm getting an "invalid ISO date" error when attempting to project this field. Code is:-

```
var testDateString = "2018-03-10T00:00:000Z"

db.getCollection('updates').aggregate([
{$match:{"summary_display_tags.Source": "whatever" }},
{$project:{_id:0, source_id:"$source_id", update_date: { $concat: [ {$substr: [ "$date_modified", 0, 10 ]},"T00:00:000Z"]}  }}
, {$project:{_id:0, source_id:"$source_id", update_date_string: "$update_date"
, updated_date: {$add: [new ISODate("$update_date")] }
//, updated_date2: {$add: [new ISODate(testDateString)] }
}}
])
```

What I don't understand is that if I try the projection using the variable string (i.e. updated_date2) it works fine however I'm stuck with the error trying to add a date based upon the projected field string...

We're on 3.2 here so I don't have the option of $dateToString. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In honour of receiving the much coveted "Tumbleweed" badge, having received no responses, I thought I'd post what I landed up doing in case anyone else stumbles into this same issue...

As it seemed impossible to cast a string field on to date field in the Aggregation pipeline, I did the work in php:-

```
$greatestAcceptableDate = new MongoDate(strtotime( "-14 days"));

$cursor = db.getCollection('updates').find(array("summary_display_tags.Source"=> "whatever"));
foreach ($cursor as $rec){   
   $recordTS = $this->buildTimestamp(strtotime(str_replace('-','/',substr($rec['date_modified'],0,10)).' 00:00:00'));
   if ($recordTS < $greatestAcceptableDate){
   db.getCollection('updates').remove("_id": $rec('_id'));
}
```

Doing so here gave me comparable date fields to use which seemed impossible given the issue with the mongo aggregate query...